# Пространство имен mvc5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Здравствуйте. Я создал 3 объекта, и хочу из первого объекта вызвать со второго. У меня не видит простанство имен первого объекта.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using SportsStory.Domain.Entities;
using SportsStory.Domain.Abstract;
using System.Web.Routing;
using Ninject;
using Moq;

namespace SportsStory.WebUI.Infrastructure
{

    public class NinjectControllerFactory:DefaultControllerFactory
    {
        private IKernel kernel;
        public NinjectControllerFactory()
        {
            kernel = new StandardKernel();
            AddBindings();
        }
        protected override IController GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
        {
            return controllerType==null? null: (IController)kernel.Get(controllerType);
        }

        public void AddBindings()
        {

        }
    }

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SportsStory.Domain.Entities
{

    public class Product
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
        public string Category { get; set; }
    }
}
}
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using SportsStory.Domain.Entities;

namespace SportsStory.Domain.Abstract
{
    interface IProductRepository
    {
       IQueryable<Product> Products { get; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66628/discussion-on-question-by-----mvc5).

Answer (score 0):

Во первых у вас ошибка с закрывающейся скобочкой в неймспейсе, и еще у вас как я понял весь код в одном файле, так не стоит делать.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using SportsStory.Domain.Entities;
using SportsStory.Domain.Abstract;
using System.Web.Routing;
using Ninject;
using Moq;

namespace SportsStory.WebUI.Infrastructure
{

    public class NinjectControllerFactory:DefaultControllerFactory
    {
        private IKernel kernel;
        public NinjectControllerFactory()
        {
            kernel = new StandardKernel();
            AddBindings();
        }
        protected override IController GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
        {
            return controllerType==null? null: (IController)kernel.Get(controllerType);
        }

        public void AddBindings()
        {

        }
    }
//Неймспейс не закрыт

using System; //Этот неймспейс уже был добавлен вверху
using System.Collections.Generic; //Этот неймспейс уже был добавлен вверху
using System.Linq; //Этот неймспейс уже был добавлен вверху
using System.Text; 
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SportsStory.Domain.Entities
{

    public class Product
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
        public string Category { get; set; }
    }
}
} // Лишняя закрывающаяся скобочка
using System; //Этот неймспейс уже был добавлен вверху
using System.Collections.Generic; //Этот неймспейс уже был добавлен вверху
using System.Linq; //Этот неймспейс уже был добавлен вверху
using System.Text; //Этот неймспейс уже был добавлен вверху
using System.Threading.Tasks; //Этот неймспейс уже был добавлен вверху
using SportsStory.Domain.Entities; //Этот неймспейс уже был добавлен вверху

namespace SportsStory.Domain.Abstract
{
    interface IProductRepository
    {
       IQueryable<Product> Products { get; }
    }
}
```

Если код у вас в одном файле, то у вас дублируются using, то есть во втором блоке не нужно добавлять те using, которые уже есть в первом например using System; был добавлен для файла 3 раза. Но вообще не хорошо писать все в одном файле. Вам нужно все разбить на разные файлы. Например:

NinjectControllerFactory.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using SportsStory.Domain.Entities;
using SportsStory.Domain.Abstract;
using System.Web.Routing;
using Ninject;
using Moq;

namespace SportsStory.WebUI.Infrastructure
{

    public class NinjectControllerFactory:DefaultControllerFactory
    {
        private IKernel kernel;
        public NinjectControllerFactory()
        {
            kernel = new StandardKernel();
            AddBindings();
        }
        protected override IController GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
        {
            return controllerType==null? null: (IController)kernel.Get(controllerType);
        }

        public void AddBindings()
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Product.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SportsStory.Domain.Entities
{

    public class Product
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
        public string Category { get; set; }
    }
}
```

IProductRepository.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using SportsStory.Domain.Entities;

namespace SportsStory.Domain.Abstract
{
    interface IProductRepository
    {
       IQueryable<Product> Products { get; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Все я нашел проблему. Оказывается я не добавил в ссылку SportsStory.Domain в другому объекту. Спасибо вам @ WebMorda за совет